# If statement running when false

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm attempting to write some code for a game in Java, however one of the if statements isn't working as expected.

```
if(player.gety() < y+row*tileSize){
    player.draw(g);
    System.out.println("Row:    " + y+row*tileSize);
    System.out.println("Player: " + player.gety());
}
```

When this code is run the output that I receive is:

```
Player: 200
Row:    -79.99999999968651320
Player: 200
Row:    -79.99999999968651320
Player: 200
Row:    -79.99999999968651320
```

This doesn't make much sense as player.gety() is clearly larger than y+row*tileSize. Is there any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: what is the player.gety() type?

Comment: Please post the correct code - the code you posted obviously is either missing important parts or does not produce that output. You should probably post an minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation is what's tripping you up here. Specifically,

```
"Row:    " + y+row*tileSize
```

is not the same thing as

```
"Row:    " + (y+row*tileSize)
```

In the first case, you're getting

```
("Row:    " + y)+ (row*tileSize)
```

where `y` is being converted to its String representation and concatenated onto `"Row:    "`, and then the product of `row * tileSize` is getting converted to its String representation and concatenated onto that.

In the second case, you'd be getting `(y + row * tileSize)`, a single numeric value, which would then be turned into a String representation and concatenated onto the String `"Row:    :"`

This is actually behaving as demanded by the spec. When either operand of the + operator is a String, it no longer means "addition", it means "concatenation", and concatenation does not obey the arithmetical rules of precedence. Instead, it greedily coerces its other operand to a String value and cats the two together.

This can have some unexpected results, as you've discovered. Try adding the parens as suggested above, or printing out the values of the variables individually:

```
System.out.println("y = "+ y + " row  = "+row + " tileSize = " + tileSize)
```

and it'll be easier to see what's happening.

EDIT:
I expect that you'll find that More likely, y = -79.999999999 (ie, -79.9, repeating) and row*tileSize=68651320. Adding those up you get substantially more than 200.

Comment: How is this a plausible explaination? Given the result `-79.99999999968651320` you would probably have `y=-7` and `row*tilesize=9.99999999968651320`. That would still make y+row*tilesize` about 3, still less than `player.gety()`.

Comment: More likely, y = -79.9 repeating, and row*tileSize=68651320. Adding those up you get substantially more than 200.

Comment: Please add that to the answer, maybe someone more than me will make the same mistake when trying to decompose `-79.99999999968651320` and get confused.

Comment: @skyking Good thought. Added.

Comment: Thanks with was actually the issue, that's been bugging me for ages I never thought of that. Oddly enough y != 79.9 recurring and instead y = -79.99999999968651 and the 320 was row*tileSize. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't think the Row output statement is showing what you think it's showing. Also, might `player.draw(g)` modify the result of `player.gety()`? Put the output statements first in the if-true block. Output each variable instead of an expression.